# Hiding images with blank src using jquery

Tags: jquery, visibility, hidden

I have 4 sub images on a page that get their src attribute from a database. they all have a class="subImage". When there is no DB entry I would like to hide the element as opposed to have a broken link as i currently have.
I have tried in jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.subImage[src^=""]').css('visibility:hidden');
});
</script>
```

Am I way off?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass parameters to the css function as follows:

```
$(selector).css('visibility','hidden')
```

or

```
$(selector).css({'visibility':'hidden', 'newAttr':'newValue'})
```

Comment: What am doing wrong?... I have included the elelemts too:    <img class="subImage" src="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['image1']; ?>"/>
                    <img class="subImage" src="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['image2']; ?>"/>
                    <img class="subImage" src="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['image3']; ?>"/>
                    <img class="subImage" src="<?php echo $row_rs_dealItem['image4']; ?>"/>
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#imageMain').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
                            });
     </script>

Comment: Thanks... I had the link to jQuery Google CDN at the end of the page. By putting in the head, it worked. I was definitely told I could the link at the bottom as long as I used document.ready?!?! great tool (jsfiddle) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try hiding them

```
  $("img").error(function(){
       $(this).hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be with CSS.  You can use the attribute selector to select an element based on the value of it's attribute.  Like so.

```
.subImage[src=""] { /* Selects all .subImage where the src is blank. */
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  This works in all IE versions down to, and including, IE 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.subImage').filter(function(){ return this.src === ''}).hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm sure the problem is at my end but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img[src=""]').hide();
});
```