# xhtml compliance error handler event like html compliance onerror event to handle empty image

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, jquery-events, w3c-validation

The following blocks of code hide the placeholder (`imagecontent`) of dynamically populated empty images and their captions:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function empty_image_handler() {
    document.getElementById("imagecontent").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
</head>
```

---

```
<body>
<div id="imagecontent"> 
      <img src="imagearchive/<?php echo $row_images['mage_link']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row_images['image_caption']; ?>" onerror= 'empty_image_handler();' />
      </div>
</body>
```

The problem is that although the above blocks of code work perfectly with `xhtml DOCTYPE` they are `html DOCTYPE` compliance. as a result the document is not validated through w3c validation process.

Moreover, I don't want to replace the empty space in `imagecontent` div with any alternative dummy image if no images are found.

Is there any `xhtml DOCTYPE` compliance error handler event similar to `html DOCTYPE` compliance `onerror` event to handle empty image that shall be validated through the validation process?

Any reference or guideline about an alternative solution with jQuery that serves the exact purpose also shall be appreciated.

Comment: Hook in your error event handler using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript)

Comment: @Alohci earning knowledge about rocket science isn't anything hard for us if we attempt to do that but i only have scope to get through as much depth about an issue as i need based on my present situation. anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution in jQuery which even doesn't require an image id or class is:

```
$("img").error(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

and it was answered by the user named **coder** at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10447080/1799764